# How to restore a svn reverted file in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, restore, svn

I did some changes to some of the files checked out from a svn repo and mistakenly did a svn revert and all my changes was gone. Is there a way to restore my changes back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, absolutely **NO**.

If you say to Subversion it should revert a file, all changes are gone by the wind.

Only your memory can get them back.

Exception: New files you had added, will only lose their status "added", but the file will remain in this directory, only status is unknown("?")

<sub>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521332/is-there-a-way-to-recover-from-an-accidental-svn-revert)</sub>